# How to extend values in dictionaries using key in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

How do I extend the values in a dictionary from a list of dictionaries using the keys as the main constraint, say:

```
d = {'a': (), 'b': 0, 'c': "", d: ""}



l = [ {'a': (23, 48), 'b': 34, 'c': "fame", d: "who"},
      {'a': (94, 29), 'b': 3, 'c': "house", d: "cats"},
      {'a': (23, 12), 'b': 93, 'c': "imap", d: "stack"},
   ]
```

to give

```
d = {'a': [(23, 48), (94,29), 23,12], 'b': [34, 3, 94],
      'c': ["fame", "house", "imap"], 'd': ['who', 'cats', 'stack'] }
```

code used

```
for i in l:
  d["a"].extend(i.get('a')),
  d["b"].extend(i.get('b')),
  d["c"].extend(i.get('c')),
  d['d'].extend(i.get('d'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize `d` as an empty dict instead, so that you can iterate through `l` and the key-value pairs to keep appending the values to the sub-list of `d` at the given keys:

```
l = [
    {'a': (23, 48), 'b': 34, 'c': "fame", 'd': "who"},
    {'a': (94, 29), 'b': 3, 'c': "house", 'd': "cats"},
    {'a': (23, 12), 'b': 93, 'c': "imap", 'd': "stack"},
]
d = {}
for s in l:
    for k, v in s.items():
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

`d` becomes:

```
{'a': [(23, 48), (94, 29), (23, 12)],
 'b': [34, 3, 93],
 'c': ['fame', 'house', 'imap'],
 'd': ['who', 'cats', 'stack']}
```

If the sub-dicts in `l` may contain other keys, you can instead initialize `d` as a dict of empty lists under the desired keys:

```
l = [
    {'a': (23, 48), 'b': 34, 'c': "fame", 'd': "who"},
    {'a': (94, 29), 'b': 3, 'c': "house", 'd': "cats"},
    {'a': (23, 12), 'b': 93, 'c': "imap", 'd': "stack"},
    {'e': 'choices'}
]
d = {k: [] for k in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')}
for s in l:
    for k in d:
        d[k].append(s.get(k))
```

in which case `d` becomes:

```
{'a': [(23, 48), (94, 29), (23, 12), None],
 'b': [34, 3, 93, None],
 'c': ['fame', 'house', 'imap', None],
 'd': ['who', 'cats', 'stack', None]}
```

Comment: Hello thanks a lot but I want to ask say I had a next dict item l ,{e: 'choices} and wanted to take all the other items  from a to d , excluding e, how do i do it

Comment: @optimus you can look the other answer it will solve your issue because the keys to choose are hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` as follow since the default value is an empty list (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i in l:
    for k in keys:
        d[k].append(i[k])
print(d)
```

Best regard

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need to hard-code the list of keys unless the sub-dicts in the input list contain other keys.

Comment: @blhsing Yeah but i wasn't sure if its always the case in his use case

Comment: Yes, and judging from the OP's new comment the sub-dicts in the input list may contain other keys after all, in which case hard-coding the list of keys is indeed the way to go.

Comment: In general purpose when extracting some data its always nice to hardcode what you want. Even if its not the prettiest